# How to change combobox items related to other comboboxes

Tags: vba

I can't find any way to remove repeated items in my combobox, consider that my items of my combobox exist in cells an actually I want my combobox showing all unrepeated items.my second question is: suppose I have three combobox and I'm free to choose any item of first one, first column in excel is my first combobox source which shows unrepeated cells information, I want my second combobox(which its items are all items in second column in my worksheet) to show items relatedly to combobox one in a way that it just shows items in second column which are appeared in front of first combobox selected item(which can be more than one cell). I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Userform combo boxes? or ones that you use somewhere else? If you would include some of your code that would help.

Comment: Put the code that loads the 2nd one in the Change event of the 1st one.

Comment: well my code is so long ,confusing and a little hard to explain